# Blocking vulnerability sniffers on shared hosting through .htaccess file

Tags: vulnerability-scanners

I have a **website that is not using Wordpress**, and which is on a **shared hosting** running Apache.

The `.htaccess` file already has already has around 300 rules, denying IP and unwanted user agents, but there is still place for optimization.

I had a look at the website **access logs**. From a few IPs, were **attempts to access many WordPress ressources** in a short period of time (1 minute) as well as other files. These appear to me as vulnerability sniffers.

**Although my website is immune to Wordpress vulnerabilities, I want to further protect it against vulnerability sniffers** and unfriendly bots.
Also, I want to learn from the failed tentatives to improve my website protection.

---

**What I implemented:**

To my `deny from ...` list I added the unwanted IP, but I assume this is efficient for short term only.

I also added this rule:

```
# Block tentatives to access Wordpress ressources
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)wp-(.*)$ - [F]
```

One of the most agressive bot showed as  `#Go-http-client/2.0`, but as it may possibly be used by Google, I am not sure that blocking it would be a good idea.

---

I don't want to delegate to Cloudfare and alike.

**What else can I do, or improve?**

Should I inform the web hosting company when I find suspect logs?

Answer (score 1):

That RewriteRule does not achieve anything meaningful. You have replaced a 404 error by a 403 error. That doesn't change anything for the server. This will not block the bots.
This is almost like a **honeypot**: you act like you are trying to hide some kind of resource you don't even actually have.

And those probes are not all malicious, regardless of what you might think. There are legitimate research entities scanning the Internet for valid reasons, and being probed by bots is normal.

Of course, there is malicious traffic too but the distinction is not always clear-cut.

If some IP addresses cause **excessive traffic** you should set up **rate limiting** on your web server.
You could also set up a **WAF** (web application firewall). It should behave more cleverly with default rules than your .htaccess rules.

Go-http-client/2.0 has nothing to do with Google, besides the **user agent** can be spoofed and cannot be trusted.

Comment: Furthermore, if you want to *optimize*, you would stop using `.htaccess` altogether and disable it with `AllowOverride None`. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when